# Is it inappropriate to ask someone to justify a downvote on an answer?

Tags: discussion

So, there was a perfectly good answer from @JACK on this question: [...grounding...](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192873/is-it-possible-to-add-a-ground-to-a-vacuum)

Somebody downvoted the answer, and I suggested they account for their downvote. That comment got deleted by a mod.

So, as the title goes, was I out of line to ask? Or was I just being a little salty for an early morning comment?

Comment: I noticed your comment and saw it deleted... and laughed. Maybe I just ticked someone off or commented on their answer and they didn't like it (I don't DV, just make comments to improve it). We want a positive attitude here but sometimes it's hard. I've questioned a few DV's too. Then I just UV to cancel it out.  It's only -2 so not going to loose any sleep over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments should be used for the following ([from our help pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)):

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated).

A comment to an unknown person that's unlikely to ever see the message, there's little value to them. That said, they happen all the time, and are often left untouched.

I'd also recommend keeping comments [positive and constructive](https://diy.stackexchange.com/conduct) on the site to be welcoming of others, anything that could be seen as combative by someone else may be flagged for mods to remove. So instead of demanding that someone explain themselves, inquire how the answer could be improved. Still, that's unlikely to ever be answered, so my suggestion in that case is to simply add your upvote since that will more than offset any points lost by someone receiving a downvote.

Comment: Perhaps upvoting answers should continue and all downvoting should be stopped. Good answers will get upvotes and poorer ones will not. Close votes continue as usual as 5 are needed and they, by design, come with a (generic) comment.

Comment: You can't close-vote an answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think you missed my point.